# How to install old version of datastax-agent for opscenter in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, opscenter, datastax-enterprise

when i am trying to manually install agents through yum  latest version of agent is getting installed rather than the version i am currently using, how can i install the version of agent i want do i need to specify anything in  datastax repo ??

I tried installing through opscenter but couldn't connect. For opscenter to be able to login into the node i had given username, password &  i am pasting whole private key file (.ppk)  into opscenter login credentials i am i doing it wrong ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install a specific verison of a yum package using "yum install package-version".  For instance, you can perform "yum install datastax-agent-5.2.4-1"